# Pyspark: encoding chinese chararacters when saving dataframe as csv file

Tags: csv, encoding, pyspark, unicode-string

I tried to save a dataframe that has columns containing Chinese letters by using this method:

```python
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv(r'path\...\file.csv')
```

But the output contains strange characters instead of Chinese letters.

Answer (score 4):

Try encoding it in UTF-8 and make sure you read your text file with the appropriate encoding:

```python
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").option("encoding", "UTF-8").csv(r'path\....\file.csv')
```

Comment: the output still contains strange characters like that ( é«˜å³°ä¸“çº¿104è·¯)

Comment: Did you make sure it does not come from your text editor and that you are reading the file using UTF-8 format ?

Comment: Also I'm saying UTF-8 but it might be a different encoding. Check the encoding of your input beforehand.